# PHP: A quick login function?

Tags: php, authentication

Is this function good for a quick login function with only one user?

```
function auth($post, $session)
{
    if(isset($post["username"]) && isset($post["password"]))
    {
        $session["user"] = new stdClass();
        $session["user"]->username = $post["username"];
        $session["user"]->password = $post["password"];
    }

    if(isset($session["user"]))
        if(is_object($session["user"]))
            if($session["user"]->username == "admin" && $session["user"]->password == "test")
                return true;

    return false;
}
```

It works but, must it be improved?

Comment: One possible improvement: you could add the user object to the session only if the login was successful.

Comment: This will definitely work but it is less than secure and would only make sense in a development/test environment.  I would not put something like this on a production server.

Comment: @Joe: Why wouldn't you, though? In what way is it less than secure? (I mean, hashing and salt would be a big improvement - but it's actually better than a database for a simple single-user system.)

Comment: @Joe what's not secure about it other than having an obvious username and password?

Comment: Hard-coding user credentials is never a good idea.  I mean, if the app is for generating GIFs of ponies galloping on rainbows, have at it.  :)

Comment: I wouldn't because of the plaintext password. If you added some md5 in there it would be a little better.

Comment: Why go through all the rigmarole of setting array key object thingamadings if the only thing you're doing with them is test for equality? You can abbreviate this whole function down to `return $post['user'] == 'admin' && $post['password'] == 'test'`.

Comment: @deceze +1 for using (although misspelled) "rigamarole" and "thingamadings" in the same comment.

Comment: @deceze sure it will work after the user clicks on submit on the login form. Whats gonna happen on the next page where there's no $_POST?

Comment: Yes, but this function doesn't do anything besides returning true or false, so you don't need all the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the session to track whether the user is logged in or not. For example, in the login page, only set the username in the session if the user authenticates properly. Logout page clears it. Then your other pages can check if the username is set in the session or not. No need to store entered password (recommend against).